# SendMessage security

Tags: windows, c++

I have a C++ app that registers a global CBT hook. However, when my program exits, I want to deregister the hooks *and also* unload the DLL that registered them so that it can be replaced by an updater program. However, this program is a security program, so I don't want to use `SendMessage` to tell other processes with my DLL loaded to unload it, because `SendMessage` can be broadcasted by any process and my program would easily be defeated. Is there a more secure way to broadcast an unload message, or perhaps a secure way to use `SendMessage`?